# How can add/verify dynamically domains and email addresses to amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I used a service for mailing my users and that service uses amazon SES to send emails.

When I signed up and did setup a sender agent, that service just required two things:

1. company name which I typed "cmpny".
2. agent name which I selected from a predefined list, I chose "joe" .

thus the result was a sender email address `joe@cmpny.email-service.com`(displayed just bellow the form) and after submit the form I tested the mailing feature and **it did work immediately**.

I know ([by aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html)) that an entity (either domain or email address) needs to be verified before get work therefore that requirement demands a manual operation.

How did this service (in an automatically way) ...

- verify `cmpny.email-service.com` domain in SES ?
- verify `joe@cmpny.email-service.com` address in SES?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Sending mail as other people/organizations is not usually a viable strategy.  What is the need for automation?

Comment: I ain't sure, I used this service for mailing an entire list of emails from people who assisted to an event that I sponsored, this service call them leads ... I think the need for automation is basically for hiding technical details from users like DNS records modifications but that's a whole 'nother  story, anyway my curiosity is about for how amazon SES allow this kind of setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using SES, you just need to verify the root domain, in this case **email-service.com**. Then email-service.com can create any quantity of subdomains they want using Route53 like **cmpny.email-service.com** and send emails using the created subdomain without any additional check.

Check the AWS docs page about this subject at [verify-domains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html), or the excerpt that explains it below:

> If you verify a domain with Amazon SES, you can send from any subdomain of that domain without specifically verifying the subdomain. For example, if you verify example.com, you do not need to verify a.example.com or a.b.example.com. As specified in RFC 1034, each DNS label can have up to 63 characters and the whole domain name must not exceed a total length of 255 characters.

Comment: You're absolutely right, despite I did read the docs I didn't caught that detail which it seems very clear, my bad :/

Comment: @geoom It's not your fault, there are many parts of AWS docs that don't have enough emphasis. In DynamoDB there are many features that should have had Big Alert signs to call reader attention, because when used incorrectly cause huge performance and costs side effects, like the use of **filter** and **limit**.